# new-cap rules flag missing 'new' for 'class User extends Record(DEFAULTS)'

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am using airbnb style check. One of the enabled rules is `new-cap`. It will flag missing new in case such as

```
import { Record } from 'typed-immutable';
const user = User();
```

The error message is 'A function with a name starting with an uppercase letter should only be used as a constructor'

It should be

```
const user = new User();
```

However eslint for some reason flags expressions like this:

```
class User extends Record(DEFAULTS)'
```

It is a false positive.

However can I avoid getting `new-cap` error for class declaration?

I am using eslint 3.9.1 and eslint-config-airbnb 12.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add this exception to the `.eslintrc` file

```
 "rules": {
    "new-cap": [
      "error", {
        "capIsNewExceptionPattern": "^(Immutable.)?Record$"
      }
    ],
    ...
```